# Method Signature Explanation Required

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand a complex (for me) method.

Here is the signature for the method:

```
public static List<T> GetAll<R, T>(RestClient client, RestRequest request) where R : new()
```

Now from this I understand that it will return a generic type and that it requires a RestClient and RestRequest object as parameters.

But I dont understand what the:

```
<R, T>
```

and

```
where R : new()
```

bits actually means?

Can someone elaborate please?

Comment: [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) and [new constraint (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [Generic type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Essentially, this signature says:

`public static List<T> GetAll<R, T>(RestClient client, RestRequest request) where R : new()`

`public` - accessible outside of this Assembly

`static` - non-instance, static (aka class) method

`List<T>` - returns a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` - an array-like collection where items inside it have type `T`

`GetAll<R, T>` - `GetAll` is the method name; `R,T` -> i imagine, `RequestType` and `T` where t is `ResponseType`.

`(RestClient client, RestRequest request)` are just arguments to the method

`where R : new()` - the method is only valid for types `R` where `R` has a public parameterless constructor (e.g. you can type somewhere `new R()`)

Usages could be:

`List<string> GetAll<object, string>(RestClient client, RestRequest request);`

It is not a really good signature because it is not clear why the author needs `R`.